# How do you write your layout for an Angular5 + MD2 app?

Tags: angular-material, angular5

So the Material Design 2 components are out there, waiting to be used in your app but my question is how would you structure your layout in which they rest? 
Do you use https://github.com/angular/flex-layout?
Write the layout manually? 
Using CSS Grid, Flexbox or both?

This is for a brand new web app, and I prefer writing it using modern technologies that are here to last (as much as this is possible with Web technologies...).

Answer (score 1):

You should use Angular's Flex Layout. It's also specified in the docs for Angular Material:

> Layout -> See [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

Comment: Yes, I've seen it.

Yet, its arguably claimed that Flexbox is not the best tool for entire layouts, rather for smaller sections within. CSS Grid is claimed to be the future of layouts (the bigger picture of the layout). Regarding the fact that its support is not terrific - its not important to me as the app I'm building is internal and all employees here have latest browsers so that's not an issue.

Comment: Compared to bootstrap flex-layout is convoluted and unwieldy. I don't see how this project can seriously take off in it's current form.